# Real concurrent file downloading

Tags: c#

I built an app that queries an API by downloading the contents of the URL. Each download is happening in it's own thread with this code:

```
    public void run(int id, string requestURL)
    {
        var filePath = "data\\" + id + ".xml";
        (new FileInfo(filePath)).Directory.Create();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(requestURL, filePath);

        // code to parse file
    }
```

I noticed that each of these files isn't being loaded up concurrently.

I've seen a few questions like this on here already, but in all of those cases each download was only run once. In my case I need it to re-run the download as soon as it's done.

How can I achieve something like this?

**EDIT:** Code I used to create the threads:

```
    public void startRun(object thread)
    {
        Threads t = (Threads)thread;
        DoRun DoRun = new DoRun(this);
        string kwd = t.keyword;
        t.requestUrl = DoRun.returnUrl(System.Uri.EscapeDataString(kwd));
        while (checkRunning())
        {
            DoRun.run(t.id, t.requestUrl);
        }
    }

    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchRunning = true;

        XmlDocument searches = new XmlDocument();
        searches.Load("data\\Searches.xml");

        XmlNodeList search = searches.SelectNodes("searches/search");
        var nodeCount = search.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
        {
            Threads thisThread = new Threads();
            thisThread.keyword = search[i].SelectSingleNode("query").InnerText;
            thisThread.id = int.Parse(search[i].SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);

            Thread newThread = new Thread(() => startRun(thisThread));

            newThread.Name = "SearchId: " + i;
            newThread.IsBackground = true;
            thisThread.thread = newThread;
            threads.Add(thisThread);
            newThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using to call the above run method?  This method is not async, so you must have some async code to call this.

Comment: Seems like it would be much easier using the DownloadFileAsync call and wiring up a call back to the DownloadFileCompleted Event